# jspdf - Insert text after table

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jsPDF and jsPDF-AutoTable to create and print a report. But I want to insert a text right below the table. But, as it is a dynamic table, I can't tell doc.text() the y coordinate from where to write the text. Has anyone done that before? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `doc.autoTable.previous.finalY` property like this:

```
doc.autoTable({html: '#table'});
let finalY = doc.lastAutoTable.finalY; // The y position on the page
doc.text(20, finalY, "Hello!")
```

See the [with content](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js#L99) example for sample code.

Comment: Thanks, Simon. That did the trick. I didn't found that in the docs, but it seems I didn't look deep enough. Awesome plugin, by the way! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Somewhat hidden, but it is under the `Helper functions` section.

Comment: Suppose I am using foreach loop, and in each item of loop there is a autotable and I want to print some text after the table. Suppose we have 3 items in array, By using this ```doc.lastAutoTable.finalY``` we get the coordinates of last autotable only. So text is displaying only in the end loop item. Is there any way to print just after the autotable in for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Great answer above, the key is how you will be using it in the page set up.

```
    if(doc.lastAutoTable.finalY) {
    doc.autoTable({startY: doc.lastAutoTable.finalY + 150})
```

The + 150 forces a new page, using the following

```
    orientation: "landscape",
    unit: "mm",
    format: "a4"
```